# How to run multiple separate GUI threads in JavaFX?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'd like to have multiple event dispatcher threads in single jvm process.

I know about offloading tasks to non-GUI threads, and I know that no changes to GUI structure may be done outside corresponding thread.

What I need is to run two completely separate full pledged JavaFX applications, each executed in its own event thread. The applications would be synchronized by external means. I understand that no direct interaction between the applications is allowed.

So, how to run two applications in single jvm?

Comment: If the two don't need to programatically talk to one another, then why not just launch each individually (say from the command line)?

Comment: They do talk. Using custom message queue.

Comment: X-Y requirement? The event thread is accessible through *static* references, so there is *normally only one* per VM. Its principally possible to spwan multiple by using different class loaders, but its a game of luck if this will actually work or not when native calls are involved. And there is no compelling reason to even try this.

Comment: Threading aside, it is not possible to [launch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-) two different JavaFX Application instances in a JVM: "Launch a standalone application. This method is typically called from the main method(). It must not be called more than once or an exception will be thrown.".

Comment: pretty sure java fx can run 1 per instance. you could subprocess and have each contain an end node to the queue connected at a different port. there are many different ways to handle messaging like this such as setting up a mailbox where each thread can read from a common folder.